# Mobile application development using ADF and PL-SQL

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

I am trying to design a mobile app that'll pass some input parameters from a Java-ADF front end to an Oracle SQL DB and fetch some results and display as tabular data on mobile. We intend to use Web-services for data transmission.

How should I go about it? Will creating a PL-SQL code be enough? What should the approach be if I try using customized XMLs and Request XMLs to fetch data values in variables from the DB through Webservices?

Pl. guide, asap...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement it.
The Oracle DB lets you create web services directly in it with PL/SQL.
You can also expose PL/SQL as web services using Java running in the middleware layer.
And you can also use things like the Oracle Service Bus to access the database and expose data to clients.